# I'm having trouble linking the GLEW library to my Xcode Project

Tags: c, xcode, glew

I'm currently trying to follow the OpenGL intro guide [here](http://duriansoftware.com/joe/An-intro-to-modern-OpenGL.-Table-of-Contents.html). I've pulled the finished project straight from the git repo on the site into a new Xcode project, but upon trying to build and run I get a "GL/glew.h: No such file or directory".

I've downloaded glew from the site, and run "make" and "make install". I can see 3 libGLEW files in /usr/lib, and 3 header glew related header files in /usr/include/GL. This all leads me to believe it's installed fine.

Following a couple of ideas from googling, I tried adding the /usr/lib and /usr/include/GL paths to the relevant search paths in the project info, but that still gave the same problem. I also tried adding "-lGLEW" to the 'Other Linker Flags' option.

The include in the C source is simply

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
```

What am I missing?!
Thanks for any help

Accepted answer works, the recursive box in XCode also needs to be checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `#include` it using `#include`  then the search path has to be simply `/usr/include`. Try adding `/usr/include` to your header search paths in your Xcode project and then it should be able to find the header.

Comment: Awesome. That did it mate, thanks. Of course it's presented me a whole bunch of new problems to fix, all part of the fun though eh.

Comment: i receive this error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_glewInit", referenced from: